# Typescript - I can't make my generic observable resolver async

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In order to keep my code cleaner I want to make a generic method to return data from observables that also unsubscribes once the data is returned. It returns data, but it often returns data too late while the code has moved on which doesn't work well on a login page...

```
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { Type } from "@angular/compiler";

export async function resolveObseravableData<T>
  (obs: Observable<any>, classReference: { new (): T}) : T {

    let instance = new classReference();

    let obsRes = await obs.subscribe((data: T) => { instance = data; },
    (err: Error) => {   
       throwError(`Error in utility.functions.resolveObseravableData: ${err.message}`); })

    obsRes.unsubscribe();
    return instance;
}
```

When I add async to the function header I get "Type T is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3" because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value."

I'm new to angular/typescript and I read that Observables should be unsubscribed from to prevent memory leaks, however a lot of code looks like below and short of turning it into a variable I don't know of any way to unsubscribe.

```
this.authService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value).subscribe(
data => {
    if (data) {
        console.log('logged in ' + this.authService.currentUser.email);
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    } else {
        console.log('currrent user is null');
    }
}, 
err => {
    console.log('error on login' + err.message);
});
```

Using the resolver to replace the above:

```
if (resolveObseravableData(
  this.authService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value), Boolean)) {
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
} else {
    console.log('currrent user is null');
};
```

Is this idea of an observable resolver just a bad idea or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: cant you get away with it with something like `async unwrapObs(o: Observable<T>): Promise<T> { return o.pipe(first()).toPromise(); }` ?

Comment: @cghislai, Wow! Yeah that worked perfectly. You have my gratitude! If you want to put that as an answer I'll mark is such.

`export async function unwrapObs<T>(o: Observable<T>): Promise<T> { return o.pipe(first()).toPromise(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a view model property for the subscription that you can unsubscribe from:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs;

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor (
    private yourService: YourService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.yourService.yourObservable$.subscribe(state => {...});
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

as an alternative, you can use a Subject to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. See: https://medium.com/@stodge/ngrx-common-gotchas-8f59f541e47c for an example.

Of course, the `| async` pipe will also unsubscribe for you.

Comment: This is a nice and clean pattern that I'll make use of, thank you! I also found some info on using the $ symbol for observables and will apply that, thanks to your example.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that observable subscriptions need to be cleaned up or you can have memory leaks.  But in cases like your `login` example, they clean themselves up automatically:

If an observable completes (successfully or with error) then the subscription is automatically released and you do not need to worry about it.  So in your example where you are calling a login service, it is a fairly safe assumption that this service returns an observable that will only produce a single value and then will complete.  Thus once you observe the login result, the subscription gets disposed and you are good to go.

The advice to cleanup your subscriptions really applies to those cases where you are subscribing to an observable that may return many values and you may want/need to stop listening before they all arrive.  In those cases, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911867/674326) from the other @Brandon provides a good pattern for unsubscribing.

Comment: Thanks, that info helps a lot - I didn't realize they could clean themselves up in certain cases, I was just guessing they would hide out in memory somewhere.

I'm used to cleaning things up in the .Net world using Dispose because it was pretty unreliable and using ngOnDestroy will work well.

Comment: Just a note that some, but not all pipe-able operators do close their connections. A couple of examples would be `take()` and `distinctUntilChanged()`.